# Remove duplicate pair in string

Tags: r

In a string variable I would like to remove both parts of a duplicates; so that I only select the unique strings. That is:

I have a string

```
MyString <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "aaa", "ddd")
```

I would like to remove both pair of a duplicate; and thus select:

```
[1] "bbb" "ccc"
```

With not luck I tried:

```
 unique((MyString)
```

Comment: not totally a duplicate, as my first answer for instance doesn't apply to the current duplicate link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- table(MyString)
names(x[x==1])
[1] "bbb" "ccc"
```

also:

```
MyString[ !duplicated(MyString) & !duplicated(MyString,fromLast = T) ]
[1] "bbb" "ccc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the set of duplicates

```
dups = MyString[ duplicated(MyString) ]
```

and drop all occurrences in the set

```
MyString[ !MyString %in% dups ]
```

Alternative:

```
setdiff(MyString, dups)
```

The table-based solution from @Moody_Mudskipper provides more flexibility, e.g., to choose strings that occur twice. An alternative (probably faster than but analogous to `table()`-solutions, when `MyString` is long), create a index into the unique strings, find the number of times each unique string is matched (`tabulate() == 1`) and use these to subset the unique strings:

```
UString = unique(MyString)
UString[ tabulate(match(MyString, UString)) == 1 ]
```

or save the need to create `UString`

```
MyString[ which(tabulate(match(MyString, MyString)) == 1) ]
```

Alternative: sort and then find runs of length 1.

```
r = rle(sort(MyString))
r$values[ r$lengths == 1 ]
```

For performance, here are some functions implementing the various solutions

```
f0 = function(x) x[ !x %in% x[duplicated(x)] ]
f1 = function(x) setdiff( x, x[duplicated(x)] )
f2 = function(x) { ux = unique(x); ux[ tabulate(match(x, ux)) == 1 ] }
f3 = function(x) x[ which( tabulate( match(x, x) ) == 1 ) ]
f4 = function(x) { r = rle(sort(x)); r$values[ r$lengths == 1] }
f5 = function(x) { x = table(x); names(x)[x==1] }
f6 = function(x) x[ !duplicated(x) & !duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE) ]
```

evidence that they produce identical results

```
> identical(f0(x), f1(x))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(x), f2(x))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(x), f3(x))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(x), f4(x))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(x), f5(x))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(x), f6(x))
[1] TRUE
```

`f5()` (also the original implementation) fails for `x = character(0)`

```
> f1(character(0))
character(0)
> f5(character(0))
NULL
```

`f4()` and `f5()` return values in alphabetical order, whereas the others preserve the order in the input, like `unique()`. All methods but `f5()` work with vectors of other type, e.g., `integer()` (`f5()` always returns a character vector, the others return a vector with the same type as the input). `f4()` and `f5()` do not recognize unique occurrences of `NA`.

And timings:

```
> microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x), f5(x), f6(x))
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 f0(x)   9.195  10.9730  12.35724  11.8120  13.0580   29.100   100
 f1(x)  20.471  22.6625  50.15586  24.6750  25.9915 2600.307   100
 f2(x)  13.708  15.2265  58.58714  16.8180  18.4685 4180.829   100
 f3(x)   7.533   8.8775  52.43730   9.9855  11.0060 4252.063   100
 f4(x)  74.333  79.4305 124.26233  83.1505  87.4455 4091.371   100
 f5(x) 147.744 154.3080 196.05684 158.4880 163.6625 3721.522   100
 f6(x)  12.458  14.2335  58.11869  15.4805  17.0440 4250.500   100
```

Here's performance with 10,000 unique words

```
> x = readLines("/usr/share/dict/words", 10000)
> microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x), f5(x), f6(x), times = 10)
Unit: microseconds
  expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
 f0(x)   848.086   871.359   880.8841   873.637   899.669   916.528    10
 f1(x)  1440.904  1460.704  1556.7154  1589.405  1607.048  1640.347    10
 f2(x)  2143.997  2257.041  2288.1878  2288.329  2334.494  2372.639    10
 f3(x)  1420.144  1548.055  1547.8093  1562.927  1596.574  1601.176    10
 f4(x) 11829.680 12141.870 12369.5407 12311.334 12716.806 12952.950    10
 f5(x) 15796.546 15833.650 16176.2654 15858.629 15913.465 18604.658    10
 f6(x)  1219.036  1356.807  1354.3578  1363.276  1372.831  1407.077    10
```

And with substantial duplication

```
> x = sample(head(x, 1000), 10000, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x), f5(x), f6(x))
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 f0(x)  1.914699  1.922925  1.992511  1.945807  2.030469  2.246022   100
 f1(x)  1.888959  1.909469  2.097532  1.948002  2.031083  5.310342   100
 f2(x)  1.396825  1.404801  1.447235  1.420777  1.479277  1.820402   100
 f3(x)  1.248126  1.257283  1.295493  1.285652  1.329139  1.427220   100
 f4(x) 24.075280 24.298454 24.562576 24.459281 24.700579 25.752481   100
 f5(x)  4.044137  4.120369  4.307893  4.174639  4.283030  7.740830   100
 f6(x)  1.221024  1.227792  1.264572  1.243201  1.295888  1.462007   100
```

`f0()` seems to be the speed winner when duplicates are rare

```
> x = readLines("/usr/share/dict/words", 100000)
> microbenchmark(f0(x), f1(x), f3(x), f6(x))
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f0(x) 11.03298 11.17124 12.17688 11.36114 11.62769 19.83124   100
 f1(x) 21.16154 21.33792 22.76237 21.67234 22.26473 31.99544   100
 f3(x) 21.15801 21.49355 22.60749 21.77821 22.54203 31.17288   100
 f6(x) 18.72260 18.97623 20.29060 19.46875 19.94892 28.17551   100
```

`f3()` and `f6()` look correct and fast; `f6()` is probably easier to understand (but only handles the special case of keeping words that occur exactly once).